# How to inject custom modules after accessing from services

Tags: angularjs

I was injecting custom modules as following.

```
$ample.lineMonitoring = angular.module('lineMonitoring', ['faultEvents','disturbances','waveforms','logI', 'dnp3Points', 'beagle']);
```

It was working fine.

here, i have different services and mentioned these injectors into that services/

```
custService.values = ['faultEvents','disturbances','waveforms','logI', 'dnp3Points', 'beagle']
```

I am having like this into service.

I need to get these list from services.  for that, need to inject service first then inject other modules.

How to do that?

Comment: Form the question correctly and meaningfully.

Comment: You can inject custom modules only if you are injecting to the app module in Which service is defined

Comment: instead of a service can't u make a ajax call and retrieve module data and construct module .

Comment: No. i need to maintain locally only. I have more no.of config there